# Java loops confusion

Tags: java, loops

I have a question regarding to the outer loop for creating triangle or pyramid, generally we code it with 3 "for", first one is the line, second one is the space and third one is the "*", however, sometimes I am confused about the first for which is the outer loop, for example:

```
          *
        * * *
      * * * * *
```

for the above pyramid, the first loop should be `for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)` or `for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)`?

Comment: We don't write code for you. Really, if you can't figure it out, just try it out and see how many iterations the outer loop needs. You don't need to get your code right at the first time, you learn much more by just writing programs and then debug them if something's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it with this **HINT**:-

```
for (int i = rows; i > x; i--) { ... }
```

For each row, you have to first print some spaces and then print stars. The number of spaces should decrease by one per row, and the number of stars should increase

**UPDATED WITH FULL CODE:-**

```
class Pyramid
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         int x=11;
         int y=x/2; // spaces
         int z=1; // *`s

         for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
             for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
            {
                 System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(int k=0;k<z;k++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            y=y-1;
            z=z+2;
            System.out.println();  //new line
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking this will bring the OP in even more confusion. The iteration direction doesn't really matter that much for this problem. Also, it would seem that the OP already has code for generating triangles, but they simply have trouble modifying it. (Of course, the OP should post their code first.)

Comment: @MattiasBuelens:- I fully agree with you but I have just explained how OP can proceed with the problem. **For each row, you have to first print some spaces and then print stars. The number of spaces should decrease by one per row, and the number of stars should increase**

Comment: Fair enough. I'd guess their code already works like that, but we'd need to see it to verify that.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens:- Yes for sure. Even I would update my answer in  that case but for now this is probably a good **HINT** for OP :)

Comment: hi guys, thank you for the post, for my question above, the"i"in the first loop should be 5 or 3?? 5 which means "i" control how many * will be printed, 3 which means "i" control the line of the pyramid.

Comment: @user2711992:- And if you have still any confusion please post your code so that we can understand what problem you are facing!!! :)

Comment: Thank you Rahul,are the three loops in your answer indicating line, space and *? if they are, why the first loop i<5, as the the pyramid only has 3 lines, not i<3?

Comment: @user2711992:- Did you tried this example. I mean did you execute this program as I changed it a bit. This prints 5 lines. ;)

Comment: Hi,yes, I tried, thank you so much for your assistance, for the space loop, why is j++? as the # of space is decreasing following with each line, is it not j--??

Answer (score 0):

```
class Pyramid
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         for(int j=1;j<=5;j+=2)  //for lines 
         {
              for(int i=1;i<=j;i++)  //for stars and spaces
              {
                  System.out.print("* ");
              }
              System.out.println();  //newline
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, you indicated the first loop is line, but by using your code, it printed 3 lines,so why did you use j<=5 but not j<=3? I think 5 is actually the # of stars, right? But your first loop is about the lines